# knockoutjs can I use a component as a table row

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, components

I want to use a component as a table row template, but can't seem to find a way, is this possible?

When I do the below, it doesn't put the component in the tbody, it puts it above the table.

Component

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <reportingline params='name: "Phil"'></reportingline>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Template

```
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: col1"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that does not look to be possible. From the [Polymer FAQ](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/faq.html#option-tr):

> Until the addition of HTML `<template>`, certain elements like `<select>`, `<table>`, and others had special parser rules to prevent anything other than `<option>` and `<tr>` from being their children, respectively. Because of these legacy rules, browsers that don’t support `<template>` will lift unexpected elements out of context and make them siblings [..]

So the only way to treat custom elements as table rows — at least in some modern browsers — would be to use the HTML `<template>` tag, which Knockout components do not use.

Allowed elements inside `<table>` according to the [WHATWG HTML standard document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element) are

> In this order: optionally a `caption` element, followed by zero or more `colgroup` elements, followed optionally by a `thead` element, followed optionally by a `tfoot` element, followed by either zero or more `tbody` elements or one or more `tr` elements, followed optionally by a `tfoot` element (but there can only be one `tfoot` element child in total), optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

(*"script-supporting elements"* being `<script>` and `<template>`)

The best workaround might be to make up your own custom `<table>` tag as well and give it proper styling through `display: table`. If you do so, please consider giving it semantic meaning as well through ARIA roles such as [`grid`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#grid).

Comment: whoever gave you a downvote for that needs a talking to - a great answer that actually explains the underlying cause!

Comment: This explained my troubles, thanks! Some answers can have long useful lifetimes :-)

Answer (score 9):

Use the virtual component binding. This approach allows you to use your component without a wrapper element.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko component: { name:"reportingline", params: { name: 'Phil' } } --><!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually does work.